# RAM modules compadibility

Tags: laptop, memory, ddr3, ddr2

My current laptop has 3GB (1x2GB, 1x1GB) of DDR2 RAM installed, and they run at 667MHz.
I just ordered a new laptop, that comes with 2GB (2x1GB) of DDR3 RAM that runs at 1066MHz.

Is there any compatibility with the two? Can I install the 2GB stick in my old laptop in the new laptop, and have both DDR2/DDR3 and 667MHz/1066MHz operating together? Or should I buy a new RAM stick for my new laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DDR2 and DDR3 are electrically and physically incompatible, sorry. You'll need to get new DDR3 SODIMMs if you want to upgrade.

On the plus side, I suppose, DDR3 happens to be the current best value for your money, as DDR2 production is ramping down due to it being "last-gen". OTOH, you could pawn off your DDR2 on Fleabay or something and quite possibly make up the difference. :)

Comment: Perfect answer to my question, thanks!
I can probably sell both sticks from my old laptop. Unfortunately it won't be computing for much longer.

Great idea, and thanks again!

Comment: Hi @teejmya, if this answer was helpful, you should accept it by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: It didn't let me at the time it was answered! Dylan answered my question really quickly.

Answer (score 3):

DDR2 and DDR3 use different timing protocols (and possibly different pin counts, not sure about that). Grab a new stick.